# Grenades and healing items no longer disassemble into items in Cyberpunk 2077

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I was disassembling Gash Antipersonnel Grenades and I started noticing that it no longer gave me any components back. I started noticing this happening for other items as well such as Maxdocs and Health Boosters, is there a requirement for when an item would stop yielding components during disassembly?

Comment: How many of the items do you have when you are trying to disassemble them? can you provide a screenshot of your inventory with the item selected that you are trying to disassemble?

Comment: As it turns out, selling/using/dropping all the items and then recreating them fixes this issue.